# search a string and if ti correct to put a number in google spread sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am tring to to check if the number is exist in a string 
if it exist I want to put the number
what is wrong with this command?

=if((FIND("480",I10)),480,if((FIND("430",I10)),430,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the FIND is unsuccessful, then a #VALUE! error is returned, and this error will be passed through no matter what.

Try:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("480",I10)),480,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("430",I10)),430,0))`

or another way:

`=--IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(I10&"","480|430"))`